# Why my session is getting lost on the page redirect?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I know its again the same question however I tried all and troubleshooted, but not getting why in this context I am getting error

Thanks in advance

**loginpage.php**

```
<?php 
   include('crud.php');
   // code
    if($_POST['login']=='ok'){      
        $r=base::login($_POST);
        if($r==true)
        {
            var_dump($_SESSION['login']); // here I am getting the session it on the same page 
            header("location: index.php");
            die();
        }
        else
        {
            $msg="Username or Password is Incorrect";
        }
    }
    // code
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
include('crud.php');
// code

var_dump($_SESSION['login']);  // here its lost

// code
?>
```

**crud.php**

```
<?php
@ob_start();
@session_start();
ini_set('error_reporting',1);
// db call
// other functions
$_SESSION['login']=$sql->id; // here session is created
return is_numeric($sql->id)? true :false;

?>
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

In one file you use $_SESSION['loginId'] and in the others you use $_SESSION['login'].

You can also use var_dump($_SESSION) to see all elements of the $_SESSION Array.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine for me.Even after using $_SESSION['loginId'] in one file the 'login' key is still available in $_SESSION global array.Hence, in index.php it echoes the 'login' key values b'coz it's set in the crud.php.